# Bitrix расположение реализация класса CMain

Tags: битрикс

Где в битриксе находится модуль `CMain` ?

Хочу чуть поправить реализацию метода `IncludeComponent`

Comment: А что именно вас не устраивает в реализации метода `IncludeComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/main.php

Оно?

Comment: Не могу не дополнить ответ советом не править классы битрикса, потому что это сильно осложнит обновление. Уж CMain-то всяко будет меняться от версии к версии главного модуля.

Comment: Обновлению это не помешает, оно просто затрёт все изменения. В данном случае можно переопределить метод в local и проблем не будет.